# Digi 003R with Pro tools LE

Tags: pro-tools

I have protools Le 8 Mbox 2 pro. I want to find out if the digi 003r would be able to connect with a 16 channel mixer so that I can record 16 channels separately onto pro tools Le?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the specs here and see...

http://www.avid.com/US/products/003-Rack

Answer (score 1):

Not unless the mixer has 4 line level outs, plus an ADAT/Lightpipe out. You might want to look into an M-Audio Octane. It's an 8 channel pre-amp that has an ADAT out. I installed one to good effect in a community college t augment an LE system. It worked great. That would at least give you 12 channels. Add in a mixer that has 4 line level outs, and you would have your 16 channels of record.